# Closing chrome incoginto window via terminal or applescript

Tags: macos, google-chrome, terminal, applescript

Was hoping someone could help me with code that would detect whether an incognito window (or multiple incognito windows) was open, and if so close it/them.

I found the below code which will achieve this if the only window open was incognito, but unsure how to implement a loop to check all open windows and close only those that are incognito.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
if exists window 1 then
    if mode of window 1 = "incognito" then
        -- insert your code here
    end if
end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a repeat loop to close all the incognito windows. You can do it with an "every window whose mode is" qualifier. Like so:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to close (every window whose mode is "incognito")
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.